# How to set MaxH264SliceBytes property of VTCompressionSession

Tags: video, frame, h.264, video-toolbox

iOS `VTCompressionSession` has a property which is `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxH264SliceBytes`. However, I cannot set the `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxH264SliceBytes` property of `VTCompressionSession`. It returns a -12900 error code (kVTPropertyNotSupportedErr) and the description in VTCompressionProperties.h file says "If supported by an H.264 encoder, the value limits the size in bytes of slices produced by the encoder, where possible."

So I understand that usage of this property is supported for some encoder settings. Does anybody know what that settings are?

Thanks.

Comment: anything changed since new devices released ?

Comment: same issue even with iOS 9 still not resolved.

Comment: it is still not supported on iOS 10...  BTW, is this the proper way to change the packetization mode?

Answer (score 2):

As Apple Developer Technical Support answered us:
The `VTCompressionSession` only supports configuring the maximum slice size if the dictionary returned by `VTSessionCopySupportedPropertyDictionary` contains the `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxH264SliceBytes` key.

Turns out that it is not supported by iOS 8.4 on any of the devices I've tested (iPhone 5, 6s) -> it's probably not implemented, at least not on iOS.

The technical support suggested we file an enhancement request using the [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com). I filed one, and I suggest you file one as well, as Apple priorities bug reports based on the number of duplicates filed.