# How to enable H.264 Single NALU mode on video toolbox on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, h.264, video-toolbox

I am trying to configure the video toolbox encoder on iOS 10 (iPhone 6) to enable Single NALU mode for H.264.  The default mode seems to be Non-Interleaved Mode where payload type of 28 (FU-A) is always used.  From the Apple Developer API reference, the closest APIs for that would be **kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxH264SliceBytes** and **kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxFrameDelayCount** for **VTCompressionSession**.

I want to set **kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxH264SliceBytes** to a value less than the RTP payload size and **kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxFrameDelayCount** to 1.  However, those two API's are not ever supported in iOS: [How to set MaxH264SliceBytes property of VTCompressionSession](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510311/how-to-set-maxh264slicebytes-property-of-vtcompressionsession)

So I would like to see if H.264 Single NALU mode is supported on iOS.  If so, how to set it?  Thanks!